# Fabric.js clipping/flipping bug

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I have a problem, when i'm clipping object or image, and then flipping him, and as result happend something wrong. How to fix this problem? 
I don't have any idea. 
Working fiddle: jsfiddle.net/ZxYCP/798/

PS: sorry for my english.

http://joxi.ru/bmoRxqPiR9QGry